# Custom painted JPanel won't appear in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I've been trying to come up with a program that for a physics project, but I'm having problems. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Cannon extends JFrame {
  Cannon() {
  setTitle("Cannonball Experiment");
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  Container c = getContentPane();
  c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  c.add(new ImagePanel());
  c.add(new ModifierPanel());

  setSize(400,600);
  setVisible(true);
       }

   class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawRect(0,100,200,300);
  }
   }

   class ModifierPanel extends Panel {
  JLabel Text = new JLabel("Speed"); 
  JTextField Tf = new JTextField(10);

  ModifierPanel() {
     add(Text);
     add(Tf);
  }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
  Cannon frame = new Cannon();
   }
}
```

`ModifierPanel` displays fine but the `JPanel`, which I added before the Modifier, is not being displayed.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character! Also, don't extend "Panel". Instead you should be extending `JPanel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JPanel` ImageJPanel doesn't show anything, so its dimension is (0,0).
Try to give your JPanel a dimension overriding method `getPreferredSize` like this:

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(0,100,200,300);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500,300); //for example
   }
}
```

You're using `FlowLayout` that honors `getPreferredSize` so you won't have any problems. Try and let me know...

Comment: JPanel would show up now, and I tried to draw g.drawLine(0,400,400,0);. The entire frame's dimension is (400,600), but the line would be cut off in the right upper end. I had to resize it for the line to be fully shown, even though I think the dimension (400,600) should be right. Can you help me on this?

Comment: If I get your question, your problem'll be in size resolution. You said that your entire JFrame's size is (400,600), but your JFrame consists of two JPanels, so your ImagePanel's width is less than 400. Don't try to adapt entire JFrame's size but only specific ImagePanel's size through getPreferredSize method.

Answer (score 0):

try buffered image in image panel ..

```
 public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

private BufferedImage image;

public ImagePanel() {
   try {                
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("specify image name and path"));
   } catch (IOException ex) {
        //  exception...
   }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);           
}
```

Comment: `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` -- Since **every** `JComponent` is an `ImageObserver` that would best be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`